# Calculating days between today and a date field in an Access table

Tags: date, ms-access

Hi I'm trying to calculate the number of days between a date field in my current access table and todays date. Here is what I have:

```
DAYS ON REPORT: DateDiff("d",[REPORTDATE],[DATE()])
```

The problem I am having is when I run the query I get a pop up box asking for "Date()"

I am trying to avoid adding a column for "today" and then doing the days between that column and the reportdate column if possible.

REPORTDATE is a column already existing in my table.
DAYS ON REPORT is the field/column I am creating.

Comment: [DATE()] is wrong write DATE()

Comment: Wow I cant believe it was that simple! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

When not enclosed in square brackets, `Date()` is a *function call* that returns the current system date. Putting square brackets around it turns it into a *field name*. Since there is no field with that name, the query treats it as a parameter and prompts for its value.

Solution: Get rid of the square brackets.